# Extract character from a string column given by position in another column in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

In a pandas dataframe, I'd like to extract a character from a string column at the index given by another column. For example, given the following `DataFrame`

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"s": ["ACGT", "AAGA"], "i": [0, 2]})
 
#       s  i
# 0  ACGT  0
# 1  AAGA  2
```

I'd like to extract `s[i]` for each row, to get

```
      s  i  extracted
0  ACGT  0  A
1  AAGA  2  G
```

I would think I could do something like

```
df["s"].str.get(df["i"])
```

however `.get()` only takes a single integer parameter, and not a series.

What's the best way to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

Try lambda

```
df['extracted'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['s'][x['i']],axis=1)

      s  i extracted
0  ACGT  0         A
1  AAGA  2         G
```